# Python Code Error random Rotation matrix

Tags: python, jupyter

I am running following code in Jupyetr version of the notebook server is 4.2.3   and Python 3.5.2 the first code works well but when i run second code i get the error mentioned below

```
# %load randomrotation
import numpy as np
def random_rot_mat_incl_flip(n):
    r = np.random.normal(size=(n,n))
    Q, R = np.linalg.qr(r) # A=QR
    M = np.dot(Q, np.diag(np.sign(np.diag(R)))) # diag(R)>0
    return M.astype(np.float32)

def random_rotation_matrix(n):
    M = random_rot_mat_incl_flip(n)
    if np.linalg.det(M)<0:
    M[:,0] = -M[:,0] # det(M)=1
    return M

if __name__ == "__main__":
    R = random_rotation_matrix(3)
    print(np.allclose(R.T, np.linalg.inv(R)))
    print(np.linalg.det(R))
```

My second code is

```
  # %load rr_extra_forest.py
   import numpy as np
   from sklearn.ensemble.forest import ForestClassifier
   from sklearn.utils.extmath import fast_dot
   from sklearn.tree.tree import ExtraTreeClassifier
   from randomrotation import random_rotation_matrix

    from sklearn.ensemble.base import _partition_estimators 
    from sklearn.externals.joblib import Parallel, delayed
    from scipy.stats.mstats_basic import mquantiles

    def _parallel_helper(obj, methodname, *args, **kwargs):
    """Private helper to workaround Python 2 pickle limitations"""
     return getattr(obj, methodname)(*args, **kwargs)

    class RRExtraTreeClassifier(ExtraTreeClassifier):
        def __init__(self,
             criterion="gini",
             splitter="random",
             max_depth=None,
             min_samples_split=2,
             min_samples_leaf=1,
             min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.,
             max_features="auto",
             random_state=None,
             max_leaf_nodes=None,
             class_weight=None):

    super(RRExtraTreeClassifier, self).__init__(
        criterion=criterion,
        splitter=splitter,
        max_depth=max_depth,
        min_samples_split=min_samples_split,
        min_samples_leaf=min_samples_leaf,
        min_weight_fraction_leaf=min_weight_fraction_leaf,
        max_features=max_features,
        max_leaf_nodes=max_leaf_nodes,
        class_weight=class_weight,
        random_state=random_state)

def rotate(self, X):
    if not hasattr(self, 'rotation_matrix'):
        raise Exception('The estimator has not been fitted')

    return fast_dot(X, self.rotation_matrix)

def _fit_rotation_matrix(self, X):
    #self.rotation_matrix = np.eye(X.shape[1]).astype(np.float32)
    self.rotation_matrix = random_rotation_matrix(X.shape[1])

def fit(self, X, y, sample_weight=None, check_input=True):
    self._fit_rotation_matrix(X)
    super(RRExtraTreeClassifier, self).fit(self.rotate(X), y,
                                            sample_weight, check_input)

def predict_proba(self, X, check_input=True):
    return  super(RRExtraTreeClassifier, self).predict_proba(self.rotate(X),
                                                              check_input)

def predict(self, X, check_input=True):
    return super(RRExtraTreeClassifier, self).predict(self.rotate(X),
                                                       check_input)

def apply(self, X, check_input=True):
    return super(RRExtraTreeClassifier, self).apply(self.rotate(X),
                                                     check_input)

def decision_path(self, X, check_input=True):
    return super(RRExtraTreeClassifier, self).decision_path(self.rotate(X),
                                                             check_input)

   class RRExtraTreesClassifier(ForestClassifier):
      def __init__(self,
             n_estimators=10,
             criterion="gini",
             max_depth=None,
             min_samples_split=2,
             min_samples_leaf=1,
             min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.,
             max_features="auto",
             max_leaf_nodes=None,
             bootstrap=False,
             oob_score=False,
             n_jobs=1,
             random_state=None,
             verbose=0,
             warm_start=False,
             class_weight=None,
             scaling=True):
    super(RRExtraTreesClassifier, self).__init__(
        base_estimator=RRExtraTreeClassifier(),
        n_estimators=n_estimators,
        estimator_params=("criterion", "max_depth", "min_samples_split",
                          "min_samples_leaf", "min_weight_fraction_leaf",
                          "max_features", "max_leaf_nodes", "random_state"),
        bootstrap=bootstrap,
        oob_score=oob_score,
        n_jobs=n_jobs,
        random_state=random_state,
        verbose=verbose,
        warm_start=warm_start,
        class_weight=class_weight)

    self.criterion = criterion
    self.max_depth = max_depth
    self.min_samples_split = min_samples_split
    self.min_samples_leaf = min_samples_leaf
    self.min_weight_fraction_leaf = min_weight_fraction_leaf
    self.max_features = max_features
    self.max_leaf_nodes = max_leaf_nodes
    self.scaling = scaling

    #self.estimator_weights = np.random.random((n_estimators,))
    self.estimator_weights = np.ones((n_estimators,))

def _fit_scale(self, X):
    self.Q5 = []
    self.Q95 = []
    for i in range(X.shape[1]):
        q5, q95 = mquantiles(X[:,i], [0.05, 0.95])
        self.Q5.append(q5)
        self.Q95.append(q95) 

def _scale(self, X):
    X2 = np.copy(X)
    for i in range(X.shape[1]):
        lessidx = np.where(X2[:,i]<self.Q5[i])[0]
        if len(lessidx)>0:
            lessval = -.01*np.log(1+np.log(1+np.abs(self.Q5[i]-X2[lessidx, i])))
        moreidx = np.where(X2[:,i]>self.Q95[i])[0]
        if len(moreidx)>0:
            moreval = 1+.01*np.log(1+np.log(1+np.abs(self.Q5[i]-X2[moreidx, i])))

        denominator = (self.Q95[i]-self.Q5[i]) if self.Q95[i] != self.Q5[i] else 1 
        X2[:,i] = (X[:,i]-self.Q5[i])/denominator

        if len(lessidx)>0:
            X2[lessidx, i] = lessval
        if len(moreidx)>0: 
            X2[moreidx, i] = moreval

    return X2

def fit(self, X, y, sample_weight=None):
    if self.scaling:
        self._fit_scale(X)
        super(RRExtraTreesClassifier, self).fit(self._scale(X), y, sample_weight)
    else:
        super(RRExtraTreesClassifier, self).fit(X, y, sample_weight)

def predict_proba(self, X):
    """Predict class probabilities for X.

    The predicted class probabilities of an input sample is computed as
    the mean predicted class probabilities of the trees in the forest. The
    class probability of a single tree is the fraction of samples of the same
    class in a leaf.

    Parameters
    ----------
    X : array-like or sparse matrix of shape = [n_samples, n_features]
        The input samples. Internally, it will be converted to
        ``dtype=np.float32`` and if a sparse matrix is provided
        to a sparse ``csr_matrix``.

    Returns
    -------
    p : array of shape = [n_samples, n_classes], or a list of n_outputs
        such arrays if n_outputs > 1.
        The class probabilities of the input samples. The order of the
        classes corresponds to that in the attribute `classes_`.
    """
    # Check data
    if self.scaling:
        X = self._scale(X)
    X = self._validate_X_predict(X)

    # Assign chunk of trees to jobs
    n_jobs, _, _ = _partition_estimators(self.n_estimators, self.n_jobs)

    # Parallel loop
    all_proba = Parallel(n_jobs=n_jobs, verbose=self.verbose,
                         backend="threading")(
        delayed(_parallel_helper)(e, 'predict_proba', X,
                                  check_input=False)
        for e in self.estimators_)

    # Reduce
    proba = all_proba[0]

    if self.n_outputs_ == 1:
        for j in range(1, len(all_proba)):
            proba += self.estimator_weights[j]*all_proba[j]

        #proba /= len(self.estimators_)
        proba /= np.sum(self.estimator_weights[j])

    else:
        for j in range(1, len(all_proba)):
            for k in range(self.n_outputs_):
                proba[k] += self.estimator_weights[j]*all_proba[j][k]

        for k in range(self.n_outputs_):
            proba[k] /= np.sum(self.estimator_weights[j])

    return proba
```

Getting following error

```
    print np.allclose(R.T, np.linalg.inv(R))
     ^
     SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any Help would be appriciated

Comment: This may help understanding: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function

Comment: You are running a Python3 kernel and need `print(...)`. The code above is showing a `print(...)`, so how are you getting this error?

Comment: Actually I have a big code after this code ..when i Run this code it shows done but when I run next code it shows the same error

Comment: Then you should show the code that is failing...

Comment: I have shown it